# Are these two definitions of continuity different?

Tags: logic, continuity

The first one:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \quad \exists \delta > 0 : {\textbf{x}} \in B({\textbf{x}}_0,\delta) \implies f({\textbf{x}}) \in B(f({\textbf{x}}_0), \epsilon)$$
Second one:
$$ \exists \delta > 0 : {\textbf{x}} \in B({\textbf{x}}_0,\delta) \implies \forall \epsilon>0,  f({\textbf{x}}) \in B(f({\textbf{x}}_0),\epsilon).$$

I don't see the difference, even reading them out loud in a proper English sentence, it seems to be equivalent.

Basically, the $\epsilon > 0$ term is in different places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one states that there is some $\delta$, such that for any $x$ in $B(x_0,\delta)$, it is the case that $|f(x_0)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. This means that $|f(x_0)-f(x)|$ is smaller than any positive number. So it has to be the case that $f(x)=f(x_0)$.

In return, this means that $f$ is constant on $B(x_0,\delta)$. So in order to find a witnessing counterexample you need to find a function which is not constant on any open ball. For example, an injective function like $x\mapsto e^x$.